# Method always return false Junit WebChromeClient onShowFileChooser

Tags: java, android, webview, junit4

I am a newby in writing test cases.

```
public class Abc {

    private static final MyWebChromeClient a = Mockito.mock(MyWebChromeClient.class);
    private static final WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams b = Mockito.mock(WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.class);
    private static final ValueCallback c = Mockito.mock(ValueCallback.class);
    private static final WebView d = Mockito.mock(WebView.class);

    @Test
    public void onShowFileChooser() {
        Assertions.assertThat(a.onShowFileChooser(d, null, b)).isSameAs(false);
        Assertions.assertThat(a.onShowFileChooser(d, c, null)).isSameAs(false);
        Assertions.assertThat(a.onShowFileChooser(d, null, null)).isSameAs(false);
    }
}
```

This test always gets passed even if I twist the code of a.onShowFileChooser to return true if b or c is null.

Please help here.
`MyWebChomeClient extends WebChomeClient` and `Override method onShowFileChooser`.

Comment: Post the code for `onShowFileChooser()` Without that it is difficult to judge.

Comment: @Override
    public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView a, ValueCallback<Uri[]> b,
                                     FileChooserParams c) {
        if (b == null || c == null) {
            return true;
        }
        return FileChooserFactory.handleFileChooserAction(b, c);
    }

Even with this test cases pass.